# webdriver-manager update unhandled promise rejection

Tags: selenium, protractor, webdriver-manager

I am using webdriver-manager 12.0.6 both globally and within my local project.

When I run `webdriver-manager update--standalone false` locally I get unhandled promise rejection errors:

```
$ node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update --standalone false
webdriver-manager: using local installed version 12.0.6
(node:13792) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\<MY_USERNAME>\src\<MY_PROJECT>\api\ClientApp\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chrome-response.xml'
(node:13792) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:13792) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\<MY_USERNAME>\src\<MY_PROJECT>\api\ClientApp\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\gecko-response.json'
```

When I run the same command globally everything works without issue.

```
$ webdriver-manager clean
[12:49:15] I/file_manager - removed chromedriver_2.37.exe
[12:49:15] I/file_manager - removed chromedriver_2.37.zip
[12:49:15] I/file_manager - removed geckodriver-v0.20.0.exe
[12:49:15] I/file_manager - removed geckodriver-v0.20.0.zip
[12:49:15] I/file_manager - removed gecko-response.json
[12:49:15] I/file_manager - removed standalone-response.xml

$ webdriver-manager update --standalone false
[12:49:24] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.37.zip
[12:49:25] I/update - geckodriver: unzipping geckodriver-v0.20.0.zip
```

I have tried deleting node_modules and rerunning yarn. Not sure what else is at play here. What steps can I take to further troubleshoot this?

Comment: Also, I'm running Windows 10 and I'm behind a proxy... so that's two strikes against me. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the folder: 
 `C:\Users\<MY_USERNAME>\src\<MY_PROJECT>\api\ClientApp\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium`

Run the `webdriver-manager update --standalone false` again in new opened cmd window